# Rails 3, how to write a controller/model methods to deduct a certain value based on an associated object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have Bands has_many Rewards, Rewards belong to Bands.

On the band show page I am looping through a bands rewards:

```
<% @rewards.each do |r| %>
    <b>Reward:</b>  <%= r.name %><br>
    <b>Cost:</b> <%= r.cost %><br>
    <%= button_to "Get This", buy_item_band_path(@band, @reward)%>
<% end %>
```

buy_item_band_path routes to the Band#buy_item action.  I am passing the @band and "r" to it so that I can access both.

I am handling users with Devise so I have access to current_user as well.  Basically I am trying to have a user buy a reward.  Users have a points attribute, so I am trying to do something like the following in the Band Model:

```
def pay_for_it
  unless current_user.points < self.reward.cost
    current_user.points - self.reward.cost
    current_user.save
    # SEND TWO EMAILS ONE TO THE PURCHASER AND ONE TO THE BAND ADMIN
  end
end
```

That model method is just what I think might work, but I don't know how to reference it in the controller, don't know if I should, don't know if I should somehow do this in the controller.

any help is greatly appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

First off, if you're trying to pass the reward, that code should probably read as:

```
<%= button_to "Get This", buy_item_band_path(@band, r)%>
```

I'm not sure what `@reward` would have been pulling from, but `r` will pull from the current iteration of `@rewards`.

As to the question, all of your business logic should happen inside of your models.  Controllers are just there to pass data into your models, analyze the result of model manipulations, and tell Rails which view needs to be displayed.

It sounds like your User is the object that is doing the paying, so your payment method probably belongs in the User model and should take a Reward as its only parameter.  There's no clear reason to involve the Band model at all.

The portion of your controller that handles this request will probably look something like this:

```
def buy_item
  reward = Reward.find(params[:reward_id])
  if current_user.pay_for_it(reward)
    # Send emails and then...
    # Render something
  else
    # Render something that indicates an error happened
    # or that the user didn't have enough points.
  end
end
```

And your User model will have something like:

```
def pay_for_it(reward)
  return false unless self.points >= reward.cost

  current_user.points -= reward.cost
  current_user.save
end
```

So `User#pay_for_it` will return true if the points were successfully deducted, at which point your controller can send out the emails and then render whatever view should be displayed after a purchase has been successful.

Hopefully that'll give you a better idea of how to organize logic and control flow in Rails.  Models manipulate data (business logic layer), Controllers pass information to and from the business logic layer, and Views display information.